# How to block specific IP on SonicWALL NSA240

Tags: security

We are being hammered by port scans from a specific IP address.  How can I block this IP from my SonicWALL NSA240?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a SonicWall appliance myself. Everyone is "hammered" as you say by port scans. Most people don't know they are unless an outside port scanner actually breaks through. Your sonicwall is doing its job of blocking the IP address when it "drops" the port scan. You will see this in your log files as: "Possible port scan dropped-" and is by design. You cannot stop port scans but they ARE blocked by SonicWall appliances.